# Access Denied error when I try to add a new virtual directory using a console application

Tags: c#, security, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

I have upgraded to a new server and my console application tries to create a virtual directory in IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012).

I am getting this error:

> [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] {"Access is denied.\r\n"}  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> ErrorCode 0x80070005
>
> Access is denied.
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_IsContainer()
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.CheckIsContainer()
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.Find(String name, String schemaClassName)

I tried giving all permissions but still it is giving error as per this: [Getting access denied while trying to create iis application from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553962/getting-access-denied-while-trying-to-create-iis-application-from-code)

Comment: Did you try to run it as administrator?

Comment: Can you post your code? Have the account under which the application runs access to IIS? Do you run locally / remotely? Do you use elevated mode (run as Administrator)?

Comment: hey Uriil ,Yes i have giving it permission to run it as Adminitrator but still issue is coming ..

Comment: The answer to the question you pointed to should be the correct [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15555140/724913)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting access denied while trying to create iis application from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553962/getting-access-denied-while-trying-to-create-iis-application-from-code)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This Solution worked for me ==>

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/13/iis-7-adsi-error-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x80005000-unknown-error-0x80005000.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage ..

I also have to do this to resolve Access denied error 
==> Run all Administrator in admin approval mode ==> Disabled ..

Comment: let me try things mentioned by you .. where i can find this Options ?

Comment: Open Local Security Policy and then click on Security Option and scroll down you will find "Run all Administrator in admin approval mode" ..